# Optimizing django select queries for Generic model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a generic model "EmailedItem" referencing a model "Item".

I would like to loop over my list of items and print the time the email was sent.

For now I am doing:

```
items = Item.objects.all()
for item in items:
    emailedItem = EmailedItem.objects.get(object_id=item.item_id)
    print emailedItem.created
```

The problem is that this routine needs to be run pretty quickly and it takes a lot of time to do a select on the database for each item.

Is there a better way to do so?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

Use [only](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#only) to select only specified fields in your query(both on Item and EmailedItem)

Comment: It is not hit on every iteration because of `Item.objects.all()`, it is hit because he does `EmailedItem.objects.get(object_id=item.item_id)` on each iteration

Comment: Right. This problem is an example of a common N+1 select problem. Thanks for correcting. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** Answering commenet

Create list of ids with `values_list` and then query by `__in`

```
items = Item.objects.all()
dict_of_emailtedItems = {i.object_id: i for i in EmailedItem.objects.filter(object_id__in=items.values_list('item_id', flat=True))}
for item in items:
    emailedItem = dict_of_emailtedItems[item.id]
    print emailedItem.created
```

This will generate only 2 queries to DB instead of 1 + N, where N is number of `items`

Comment: Thank you but I have to do other stuff with my item in my loop.
So, I need to loop through my list of items and not my list of EmailedItems.

Ideally, I'd have a dictionary with as a key, the ID of the corresponding Item, and as the value, the created. All in one query...

So in the loop I could easily do something like dict_of_emailtedItems[item.id]

Comment: @justinlevol see updated answer. Also if `EmailedItem` has `ForeignKey` to `Item` you could just do `emailedItem.item`, but do not forget to do `select_related('item')` for that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
It does work and I came out with a similar solution but unfortunately it doesn't help performance wise.